# Realm Interface in JAVA

Tags: java, android, realm

I used the **version 0.89 of Realm** the last year in an old project, and now I'll use the last version, so my question is :

**There's any news about Interface in java, cause I used de below?**

```
// INTERFACES

public interface NoMethodsInterface() {
// No methods
}

public interface MatchGetterInterface() {
    public getId(); // match id getter
}

// MODELS

public class Foo extends RealmObject implement NoMethodsInterface {
    private long id;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public class Bar extends RealmObject implement MatchGetterInterface {
    private long id;

    @Override
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Can anyone told me if he use interface with Realm and how it works ?

Comment: The question is not really clear. What exactly works?

Comment: are you working with realm ? if yes can you tell me how to implement interface in models ?

Comment: Interfaces in Realm work since 0.88.0

Comment: Yes, I knew but they don't work like simple interface, they need a specific implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is consistent with latest (2.3.0) version of realm library, except of [primary key](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#primary-keys) fields. You need insert `@PrimaryKey` annotation to key fields:

```
public class Foo extends RealmObject implement NoMethodsInterface {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;

    public long getId() { return id; }

    public void setId(long id) { this.id = id; }
}

public class Bar extends RealmObject implement MatchGetterInterface {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;

    @Override
    public long getId() { return id; }

    public void setId(long id) { this.id = id; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the option to add @RealmClass annotation and implement RealmModel:
https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#models

## RealmModel interface

```
Instead of extending RealmObject, your classes can implement the
RealmModel interface, adding the @RealmClass annotation
```

Class members that are objects must be declared as concrete classes however. 
You cannot persist the interface type.